# How to reproject an RDD containing raster to different crs (WGS84)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, projection, geotrellis

i have created an RDD which contains the DGM raster for a particular area and has `crs : EPSG 32632`. i want to overlay this data over a  image for further analysis which has `crs:EPSG 4326` which is also an RDD.

Although both the images lie over each other in QGIS but the projection system and there are extents are different that's why later when i try to reproject both RDD to `webmercator` it gives me a black image.

```
val (_,inputrdd) : (Int, MultibandTileLayerRDD[SpatialKey]) = biggis.landuse.spark.s3.layerFromS3(bucket, name, Some(tileSize))

   val store = new S3AttributeStore(bucket,name){
    override def s3Client = s3ClientURL()
  }
  val writer = S3COGLayerWriter(store)
  val (_,rasterrdd) : (Int, MultibandTileLayerRDD[SpatialKey]) = biggis.landuse.spark.s3.layerFromS3(bucket1, name1, Some(tileSize))

  val raster_store = new S3AttributeStore(bucket1,name1){
    override def s3Client = s3ClientURL()
  }
  val raster_writer = S3COGLayerWriter(raster_store)
```

`inputrdd` is with `4326` .

How can i reproject the rasterrdd to inputrdd projection system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `rasterrdd` is of a type `MultibandTileLayerRDD[K]` you can use all geotrellis functions to perform reprojection; it will be smth like:

```
rasterrdd.reproject(LatLng, ZoomedLayoutScheme)
```

You're welcome to look for a more detailed information into [docs](https://geotrellis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and to join our [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/geotrellis/geotrellis) for any further questions and discussions.